# trackMetric not showing up in Application Insights

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights

**I have an issue where I'm trying to add a new metric, but it's not showing up in my Application Insights metrics in the Azure Portal.**

The example below describes issue where I'm trying to track a new metric called "Number of times asked" inside a bot dialog and increment it by 1 whenever a user reaches the dialog. For this example, `timesAsked` is reset to `0` whenever the server restarts:

```
var appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
var telemetryModule = require('./telemetry-module.js');
appInsights.setup(process.env.APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY).start();
var appInsightsClient = new appInsights.TelemetryClient();
var timesAsked = 0;

bot.dialog('Greeting', session => {
    session.endDialog('Hi there!');

    appInsightsClient.trackEvent({ name: 'Greeting', properties: session.message.text });
    appInsightsClient.trackMetric({name: 'Number of times asked', properties: timesAsked++});

}).triggerAction({
   matches: /^hi/i 
});
```

Shouldn't this show up under `Custom` inside my Applications Insights resource?

[image]

The only thing showing up here is `duration`.
I've seen people having the similar issue a few years ago where their metrics did not show up in the Metrics Explorer before 5 days had passed. Is this still the case?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, it takes about 10 minutes to show up my custom metric under the Azure Portal.

[image]

So, If you're expecting some metrics that haven't appeared yet, wait 5-10 mins and click **Refresh** on the top.

Comment: Yes. Data typically takes ~10 minutes, unless there is any service outage which will be posted here: https://aka.ms/aistatus